# ANGULARJS - Saving form and passing select values as data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm rewriting a Radio Show player from jQuery / JS to AngularJS.

On the back-end, whenever the user wants to add a new time slot for a show, they would essentially select the show, the day, the start and end time. I have all of these options using SELECTS. The select options are populated via ajax queries.

Now, when the user saves the new show-time, I send the POST using `$http.post('POST/URL', data)`. Firebug says the JSON passes over, however, when I print a response with all the post attributes, none of them were set.

Any ideas?

Controller function:

```
$scope.setShows = function(data){
  d = {
    showID: data.show.id,
    day: data.day.id,
    start: data.start,
    end: data.end
  }
  ShowTimes.set(d);
}
```

POST ajax function:

```
factory.set = function(data){
  console.log(data);
  $http.post('includes/admin/set_show_time.php', data);
}
```

PHP side of the equation:

```
$showID = $_POST['showID'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

$arr = array(
  'showID' => $showID,
  'day' => $day,
  'start' => $start,
  'end' => $end
);

print json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Try: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`. Angular will pass `data` as a json encoded string in the request body, so php will not be able to auto-fill the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Thanks Yoshi. What is $data in your suggestion? each $_POST?

Comment: And actually, when I `print_r($_POST)`, it returns an empty array, therefore, nothing is passing through.  Also, When I do `$.post('includes/admin/set_show_time.php', data)` it works :(

Could it be an AngularJS bug?

Comment: `$data` is just an arbitrary variable name, but the value should be what you sent with angular (try `var_dump($data);`). jQuery post will send the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which gets auto-translated by php into `$_POST`. Whereas angular will send the data as a json string in the request body, which php can't handle automatically. What I wrote in my first comment is one of many ways to get the raw request body which is required in this case to get hold of the data sent by angular. Also this is no angular bug, it's just a different way of sending the data.

Comment: Ahhhh.. Absolutely correct, Mr Yoshi! Upon further googling, I found the following to back up your reply: 
http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/